# AWS cognito sync manager error synchronize to cloud

Tags: synchronization, amazon-cognito

I have javascript client to perform aws cognito authenticated login with provider (Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc). I can see it has been successful to get the Credential from :

```
var cognitoParam = { 
  'IdentityPoolId': 'ap-northeast-1:c8250ce6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'RoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/roleName'
  'Logins': {
     'accounts.google.com': response.detail.id_token
  }
};
var cognitoCred = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(cognitoParam);
```

It returns all credentials object. And I checked also on AWS console, the pool ID has been listed/recorded in the federated identities pool as authenticated login with provider.

After get credential, I want to work with Cognito Sync Manager to store several user Info to cloud :

```
var syncManager = new AWS.CognitoSyncManager();
syncManager.openOrCreateDataset('profileSet', function(err, dataset) {
   // dataset.get
   // dataset.put
   // dataset.remove
});
```

All methods (get, put, remove) work well, but I have an issue to run method synchronize. In example, after put new dataset :

```
dataset.put("keyTes", "english", function(err,record){
  if(!err){
    dataset.synchronize({
      onSuccess: function(dataset, newRecords) {
        console.log(newRecords);
      },

      onFailure: function(err) {
        console.log("Error while synchronizing data to the cloud: " + err);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

It shows error :

> Error while synchronizing data to the cloud: AccessDeniedException:
>   User:
>   arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/roleName/web-identity
>   is not authorized to perform: cognito-sync:ListRecords on resource:
>   arn:aws:cognito-sync:ap-northeast-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:identitypool/ap-northeast-1:c8250ce6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/identity/ap-northeast-1:653aeca2-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/dataset/profileSet

In the my IAM role, I set to  :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "default"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and the policy :

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "cognito-sync:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}

I follow the reference from the link :

[Amazon Cognito Sync Manager for JavaScript](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-js)

Anyone can help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved. I was wrong on replace my IAM role param. everything is right, only my wrong scripts.

Thank you